Did Charles II of England scoff at the idea that air has weight?
On an episode of the BBC 4 podcast Science Stories about Margaret Cavendish's 1667 visit to the Royal Society, historian Emma Wilkins remarks in passing (at about the 9:03 mark),

There is a report of King Charles II hearing about members of the Royal Society weighing air and bursting out laughing. "Oh, those people are my jesters," he is supposed to have remarked. "What a stupid idea, weighing air. Air is nothing. How can it possibly have weight?"

But do we know that this was actually the king's attitude?
As for calling them jesters, I have found a paper in Notes and Records of the Royal Society which cites Lorenzo Magalotti as reporting in 1668 that Charles was "accustomed to call his academicians by no other name than mes fus [my fools]."
And I have found in the entry for 1 February 1663/1664 in The Diary of Samuel Pepys  the report that "Gresham College [the Royal Society] he [the king] mightily laughed at, for spending time only in weighing of ayre, and doing nothing else since they sat." But that sentence admits the interpretation that Charles knew air had weight and was mocking only the scientists' bothering with so unimportant a subject as what that weight might be.
OK, but was air's having mass not widely accepted in that era? After all, as is discussed in answers to this question, even Aristotle held that air had weight.
I have found in a paper in The Journal of Applied Physiology this quote from a letter that Torricelli wrote to Michelangelo Ricci in 1644:

We live submerged at the bottom of an ocean of the element air, that by unquestioned experiments is known to have weight.

The paper's author describes Torricelli's remark in its seventeenth-century context as "dramatic" because "this concept was a major breakthrough in an area that had caused
much confusion in the past." But according to a page from PBS's Nova called "Discovering Air", Isaac Beeckman had already compared air to water back in 1618, drawn the analogy to "the pressure water exerts at depth," and "[come] up with the then radical suggestion that air has physical properties."
So the idea was in the air [pun intended?] twenty-five and even fifty years before Pepys's report of Charles's mockery. Of course, this doesn't mean that the king was even aware of the idea, let alone that he accepted it. What do we actually know about the king's beliefs in this regard?

Air having mass being ‘widely’ accepted in the small science community of the time is different from the king believing it or even caring about it.

Yes, @JonCuster, that’s exactly the point of my final paragraph.

[Possibly related.]  In the movie Smoke (1995), William Hurt relates an anecdote where Sir Walter Raleigh (I think) proves to some royal person (I forget who) that cigar smoke has weight.

I suspect the king had a less firm view about whether air had weight or not, than finding humour in what had utterly ensconced the attention of a body of learned men, compared to what naturally ensconces the attention of medieval kings. For a modern example, think of the Monty Python character talking about the different qualities of mud used as a point of humour by the writers, or the archaeological Time Team programme on TV who occasionally proceeded to talk about different qualities of mud in earnest (which had an unintentionally risible effect for many former viewers I know).

This should probably be a comment but is too long.
At the start of the seventeenth century the only standing army in Europe was that of the Ottoman Empire. The European nations employed armies made up largely of mercenaries who only fought during those months where the weather was agreeable and were retired in the winter months.  The menace of the Ottomans threat being obvious, this was about to change as the Europeans scrambled to create standing armies.
By the time of Charles II the prosperous principalities of the Netherlands had already set the precedent earlier in the century when Maurice of Nassau, Stadthouder of Holland (later Prince of Orange) began introducing the technical innovations of the day into his military such as the telescope, the first practical time-fuse for the detonation of explosives (an early sort of hand grenade), and the recently invented curb-bit which provided the cavalry with much greater control over their horses. Maurice was tutored by Simon Stevin (the mathematician and engineer) and employed Stevin to design fortifications, to establish a department of engineering at the University of Leiden, and appointed him quartermaster-general of the army.
Against this background, when Charles II granted a royal charter to what then became known as the Royal Society of London in 1662, it is extremely unlikely that he thought of its members as his “jesters”.  Charles would have placed a high value on their potential to produce valuable military technologies. Charles  was well aware of the successful example of Maurice of Nassau and he needed all of the help he could get.  England had an estimated population of approximately four-million while France’s population was estimated at approximately twenty-million. So I would argue that while he may have been perplexed by the idea of weighing air, he would not have considered the members of the Royal Society as his jesters.

So you would discount Lorenzo Magalotti's report? And the thematically very similar (and apparently eye-witness) report by Pepys that Charles "mightily laughed" at the Royal Society for busying itself with the undertaking?

@PaulTanenbaum I cannot with certainty discount Magalotti's report, but I do suggest that it is unlikely that Charles was sincere if he did call the societies members his jesters.  It would more likely have been an act of hubris by a king reestablishing his authority after the dramatic events that preceded his return from France.  Pepys' reporting of a mighty laugh may very well be accurate.  Charles was not a scientist and most likely did find the idea of weighing air to be a rather silly waste of time when more pressing matters demanded attention vis-à-vis useful military technologies.
